# Angular JS :Recursive directive pre-processing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a recursive directive the compiles an HTML element and appends to the  DOM structure. The input data I get is the JSON tree. I want to augment the tree to do some pre-processing and set a watch on the tree.

How can I do this considering I want the directive to be reusable?

Can I attach my own controller to the directive scope and do it there? Or maybe post vs pre link function?

Edit : Consider [this](https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree) way of printing a tree. This approach indents the data using css to give the effect of a 'recursive' template but does not use recusrion. If you look at the js file, it actually loops through the JSON data, add parameters to it and applies a $watch on it to notify for the click event.

On the other hand, consider the angular [way](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang/blob/master/js/directives/scopeTree.js) of using a $compile for runtime DOM manipulation. This approach is very good. I want to modify this method and add parameters to the JSON data before the directive is actually applied. While this should be trivial to do in the application controller, I want to create a reusable directive that can work out of the box like the first approach.

Hope this brings clarity.

Comment: Which 'JSON tree'? Also, what do mean by augmenting it? Any operations that need to be done before the controller fires can be placed in the directives compile function.

Comment: question is far too vague without some code